# How does an extra dimension (4D) imply an additional symmetry?

Tags: group-theory, geometry, intuition, rotations, symmetry

I was just watching this video

[Group theory 1: Introduction with Borcherds](https://youtu.be/RnqwFpyqJFw?t=160)

and he mentions how a Dodecahedron with 12 faces can be put into a 4th dimension that will allow you to flip it and then you'd have an order of 120 instead of 60 with only rotations. I guess I can imagine flipping a 2D rectangle in 3D like a card however I guess we can't "flip" in the same dimension? Can someone give me some additional intuition?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

In $\mathbf{R}^{4}$ with coordinates $(x, y, z, w)$, rotations fixing the $(x, y)$-plane have matrices of the form
$$
R_{\theta} = \left[\begin{array}{@{}cccc@{}}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\
    0 & 0 & \sin\theta & \phantom{-}\cos\theta \\
  \end{array}\right].
$$
The rotation with $\theta = \pi$ effects the reflection $(x, y, z) \mapsto (x, y, -z)$ on the three-dimensional subspace $w = 0$.

A similar trick with the last two coordinates shows that a reflection of $n$-dimensional Cartesian space may be effected by a half-turn of $(n+1)$-dimensional space.